# Weird custom VGA signal behaviour (FPGA)

Tags: verilog, system-verilog, fpga, vga

My goal is to display something on a VGA display with the resolution of 640x480px. I really want to stick with this resolution for other reasons, but we will see.

**The problem**:

Some lines appear dimmer and some appear lighter, also there is a large black border on the left side. I'm pretty sure that this is not (purely) due to my "bad signal timing" though.
*(Please ignore the white scratch)*
[image: Picture of the display]

**My setup**:

- Altera Cyclone IV FPGA
- 3x330 Ohm resistors (on R,G,B lines) (and I'm driving the VSYNC and HSYNC directly with 3V3)
- Monitor NEC MultiSync EA232WMi ([manual](https://www.sharpnecdisplays.eu/p/download/cp/Products/DesktopLCDs/Products/SupportedProducts/EA232WMi/ProductManuals/Manual-EA232WMi(english)-EA232WMi.pdf?fn=EA232WMi-UserManual-english.pdf))

**Verilog code**:

```
module vga_test (
    output wire HSYNC,
    output wire VSYNC,
    output wire enable,
    output wire r,
    output wire g,
    output wire b,
    // 50 MHz at clk
    input wire clk
    );
    
    reg [32:0] hor_counter;
    reg [32:0] ver_counter;
 
    reg [32:0] counter;
 
    always @(posedge clk) begin
        counter <= counter + 1;
 
            if (enable == 1) begin
                    if (hor_counter[2:0] == 3) begin
                        g <= 1;
                    end else begin
                        g <= 0;
                    end
            end
 
            // Vertical counter
            if (hor_counter == 1271) begin
                enable <= 0;
            end if (hor_counter == 1303) begin
                HSYNC <= 0;
            end if (hor_counter == 1494) begin
                HSYNC <= 1;
            end    
 
            hor_counter <= hor_counter + 1;
 
            if (hor_counter == 1589) begin
            // if (hor_counter == 800) begin
                hor_counter <= 0;
                ver_counter <= ver_counter + 1;
                g <= 0;
 
                if (ver_counter <= 480) begin
                    enable <= 1;                end
 
            end
 
 
        // Horizontal counter
        if (ver_counter == 490) begin
            VSYNC <= 0;
        end if (ver_counter == 492) begin
            VSYNC <= 1;
        end
 
        if (ver_counter == 525) begin
            ver_counter <= 0;
        end
 
    end
 
endmodule
```

What is very interesting, is that the monitor did not pick this up as 640x480, but as 720x480. This would maybe solve the why there is the black border, but the [user manual](https://www.sharpnecdisplays.eu/p/download/cp/Products/DesktopLCDs/Products/SupportedProducts/EA232WMi/ProductManuals/Manual-EA232WMi(english)-EA232WMi.pdf?fn=EA232WMi-UserManual-english.pdf) says that 640x480 is supported. And this is not just with this monitor, I tried some other I have on hand with similar results. Maybe there is something with the signal timing that I'm not getting? I would't be surprised if the "picture" looked stretched, similar to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36358944/verilog-vga-signal-implementation-stretched-horizontal), but this looks like a sinusoidal pattern.

Comment: Would have been better if you could get the precise pixel clock of 25.175MHz. If you have a spare PLL, use it instead of dividing 50MHz by two. Also, not quite sure your porch widths are correct, consult with http://tinyvga.com/vga-timing/640x480@60Hz

Answer (score -1):

Your code outputs a big horizontal front porch. Your display shows a big horizontal front porch.

Try moving the hsync signal closer to the end.